# Property of $Cu$ so that it is used as target in in X-ray diffraction (XRD)?

Tags: atomic-physics, diffraction, x-rays

Why only $Cu$ is used as target element in X-ray diffraction (XRD)? Why not other elements? And which rays has high intensity $k_\alpha$ or $k_\beta$?

Comment: Apart from any x-ray reasons, Cu is cheap, easily machined, and has a high thermal conductivity so it can be cooled easily - you don't want you x-ray source trying to turn into an e-beam evaporation system!

Comment: nice discussion here: http://pd.chem.ucl.ac.uk/pdnn/inst1/anode.htm

Answer (score 0):

The main requirements for choosing a target for x-ray generation is that, the material has to be metallic, have high melting point as a huge amount of heat is generated during the operation. So, the number of materials are limited. Some of the commonly used materials are Molybdenum, tungsten, Rhodium. kα lines are the strongest among the two.